# Populating environment-specific variables in .net app using GitHub Actions

Tags: .net, azure, devops, github-actions

I have taken over support for a .net application that is currently being deployed as a Azure web service using Azure DevOps.  My immediate task is to move the pipeline to GitHub Actions, which I have done.  The one thing that I could not figure out is how to replicate something that ADO currently does:  populating a web config setting during deployment:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="APP_CONFIG_URL" value="%APP_CONFIG_URL%" />
```

Is there a way to do this using GitHub actions?  I've seen some mentions of of tokenization to do this but the articles were several years old.  If there isn't a good way to do this am I better off trying to have a different config for each environment and handle the differences there?

Comment: Not knowing the specifics of azure web services, I'd guess they have a way to set environment variables differently for dev/stage/prod? Then you'd only have to pass in the environment name from gh-actions to azure. Basically, I'm saying it's your app deployment service's responsibility to set this, not gh-actions'

Comment: I ended up using this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69798688/trying-to-reference-azure-app-service-config-variable-in-code