# Trying to reference Azure App Service config variable in code

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, devops

I have seen countless posts on this subject but I have yet to get it to work.

I have a C# app that I am publishing to an Azure App service using GitHub actions.  In the application, I am trying to pull back the value of a key pair that is defined in "Application Settings" in the App Service.  I've seen various ways to do this - I am not sure if it changed as time went by.

**Application Service: Application Setting key pair:**

name:  Adam    value:  Hello

**web.config**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="APP_CONFIG_URL" value="https://localURL" />
    <add key="Adam" value="APPSETTING_Adam"/>
</appSettings>
```

**code:**

```
  string testVar1 = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Adam"]);


  return $"{testVar1} }"
```

The value of this returns "Adam".  Note that I have also tried making the webconfig value to be "%Adam" and "%APPSETTING_Adam" - those don't work either.
Note that I have no problem returning the value for "APP_CONFIG_URL", which is defined locally.

Answer (score 0):

I suck.  I neglected to hit "Save" after creating the App Service key pair.